# Draw a horizontal and vertical line on mouse hover in chart js

Tags: javascript, php, graph, chart.js, linechart

I am stuck with a problem on chart js while creating line chart. I want to create a chart with the specified data and also need to have horizontal and vertical line while I hover on intersection point. I am able to create vertical line on hover but can not find any solution where I can draw both the line. Here is my code to draw vertical line on hover.

```
    window.lineOnHover = function(){        
        Chart.defaults.LineWithLine = Chart.defaults.line;
        Chart.controllers.LineWithLine = Chart.controllers.line.extend({
        draw: function(ease) {
          Chart.controllers.line.prototype.draw.call(this, ease);

          if (this.chart.tooltip._active && this.chart.tooltip._active.length) {
             var activePoint = this.chart.tooltip._active[0],
                 ctx = this.chart.ctx,
                 x = activePoint.tooltipPosition().x,
                 topY = this.chart.legend.bottom,
                 bottomY = this.chart.chartArea.bottom;

             // draw line
             ctx.save();
             ctx.beginPath();
             ctx.moveTo(x, topY);
             ctx.lineTo(x, bottomY);
             ctx.lineWidth = 1;
             ctx.setLineDash([3,3]);
             ctx.strokeStyle = '#FF4949';
             ctx.stroke();
             ctx.restore();
          }
        }
        });
    }


//create chart
var backhaul_wan_mos_chart = new Chart(backhaul_wan_mos_chart, {
    type: 'LineWithLine',
    data: {
        labels: ['Aug 1', 'Aug 2', 'Aug 3', 'Aug 4', 'Aug 5', 'Aug 6', 'Aug 7', 'Aug 8'],
        datasets: [{
                label: 'Series 1',
                data: [15, 16, 17, 18, 16, 18, 17, 14, 19, 16, 15, 15, 17],
                pointRadius: 0,
                fill: false,
                borderDash: [3, 3],
                borderColor: '#0F1731',
//                    backgroundColor: '#FF9CE9',
//                    pointBackgroundColor: ['#FB7BDF'],
                borderWidth: 1
            }],
//                lineAtIndex: 2,
    },
    options: {
        tooltips: {
            intersect: false
        },
        legend: {
            display: false
        },
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                    gridLines: {
                        offsetGridLines: true
                    },
                    ticks: {
                        fontColor: '#878B98',
                        fontStyle: "600",
                        fontSize: 10,
                        fontFamily: "Poppins"
                    }
                }],
            yAxes: [{
                    display: true,
                    stacked: true,
                    ticks: {
                        min: 0,
                        max: 50,
                        stepSize: 10,
                        fontColor: '#878B98',
                        fontStyle: "500",
                        fontSize: 10,
                        fontFamily: "Poppins"
                    }
                }]
        },
        responsive: true,
    }
});
```

my output of the code is as follow in **WAN MoS Score graph** --
[image]

So I want to have an horizontal line with the same vertical line together when I hover on the intersection (plotted) point..

Please help my guys..Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can just add a second draw block for the y coordinate that you get from the tooltip, first you move to the left of the chartArea that you can get the same way you got bottom and top and then you move to the right on the same Y

```js
Chart.defaults.LineWithLine = Chart.defaults.line;
Chart.controllers.LineWithLine = Chart.controllers.line.extend({
  draw: function(ease) {
    Chart.controllers.line.prototype.draw.call(this, ease);

    if (this.chart.tooltip._active && this.chart.tooltip._active.length) {
      var activePoint = this.chart.tooltip._active[0],
        ctx = this.chart.ctx,
        x = activePoint.tooltipPosition().x,
        y = activePoint.tooltipPosition().y,
        topY = this.chart.legend.bottom,
        bottomY = this.chart.chartArea.bottom,
        left = this.chart.chartArea.left,
        right = this.chart.chartArea.right;


      // Set line opts
      ctx.save();
      ctx.lineWidth = 1;
      ctx.setLineDash([3, 3]);
      ctx.strokeStyle = '#FF4949';

      // draw vertical line      
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(x, topY);
      ctx.lineTo(x, bottomY);
      ctx.stroke();

      // Draw horizontal line
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(left, y);
      ctx.lineTo(right, y);
      ctx.stroke();

      ctx.restore();
    }
  }
});

var options = {
  type: 'LineWithLine',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderWidth: 1
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

**Edit:**

You should use a custom plugin for this since you dont draw everytime you move the cursor and you can enforce this by using a custom plugin:

```js
const options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderWidth: 1
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      corsair: {
        dash: [2, 2],
        color: 'red',
        width: 3
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [{
    id: 'corsair',
    afterInit: (chart) => {
      chart.corsair = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
      }
    },
    afterEvent: (chart, evt) => {
      const {
        chartArea: {
          top,
          bottom,
          left,
          right
        }
      } = chart;
      const {
        x,
        y
      } = evt;
      if (x < left || x > right || y < top || y > bottom) {
        chart.corsair = {
          x,
          y,
          draw: false
        }
        chart.draw();
        return;
      }

      chart.corsair = {
        x,
        y,
        draw: true
      }

      chart.draw();
    },
    afterDatasetsDraw: (chart, _, opts) => {
      const {
        ctx,
        chartArea: {
          top,
          bottom,
          left,
          right
        }
      } = chart;
      const {
        x,
        y,
        draw
      } = chart.corsair;

      if (!draw) {
        return;
      }

      ctx.lineWidth = opts.width || 0;
      ctx.setLineDash(opts.dash || []);
      ctx.strokeStyle = opts.color || 'black'

      ctx.save();
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(x, bottom);
      ctx.lineTo(x, top);
      ctx.moveTo(left, y);
      ctx.lineTo(right, y);
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.restore();
    }
  }]
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

**Edit:**

Updated answer for v3

```js
const options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderWidth: 1
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      corsair: {
        dash: [2, 2],
        color: 'red',
        width: 3
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [{
    id: 'corsair',
    afterInit: (chart) => {
      chart.corsair = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
      }
    },
    afterEvent: (chart, evt) => {
      const {
        chartArea: {
          top,
          bottom,
          left,
          right
        }
      } = chart;
      const {
        event: {
          x,
          y
        }
      } = evt;
      if (x < left || x > right || y < top || y > bottom) {
        chart.corsair = {
          x,
          y,
          draw: false
        }
        chart.draw();
        return;
      }

      chart.corsair = {
        x,
        y,
        draw: true
      }

      chart.draw();
    },
    afterDatasetsDraw: (chart, _, opts) => {
      const {
        ctx,
        chartArea: {
          top,
          bottom,
          left,
          right
        }
      } = chart;
      const {
        x,
        y,
        draw
      } = chart.corsair;

      if (!draw) {
        return;
      }

      ctx.lineWidth = opts.width || 0;
      ctx.setLineDash(opts.dash || []);
      ctx.strokeStyle = opts.color || 'black'

      ctx.save();
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(x, bottom);
      ctx.lineTo(x, top);
      ctx.moveTo(left, y);
      ctx.lineTo(right, y);
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.restore();
    }
  }]
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.8.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks LeeLenalee. that is what i required, can you please let me know how can we make it like we need it everywhere like this one -- https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/embed/wjVXmY?default-tab=result&editable=true&theme-id=dark

Comment: just ignore the lines and plotted series there, see the hover lines

Comment: I need the lines intersection everywhere I move the cursor

Comment: I need crosshair . finally got the exact word for the lines

Comment: Updated answer for you

Comment: thanks dear. Superb. Just one thing pending on this one as I need to show the values in y and x axis based on the that cross hair. Thanks for your time and help

Comment: LeeLanalee have you any idea how we can see the values on x-axis and y-axis on cursor selection

Comment: If the scales have a `getValueForPixel` method you can use that otherwise I don't know how to do it in v2

Comment: okay thanks LeeLenalee. will look out more on it. If you get any appropriate answer please let me know. Thanks for your support

Answer (score 15):

This is 2022, the current version of [ChartJS is 4.0.1](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/4.0.1/). So, I recommend to use this new implementation.

First, let's define a `plugin`. ChartJS's plugins has an `id` parameter, in this case less say `corsair`.

Then we define `default` variables for our plugin, like `width`, `color` and line `dash`. Additionally, our plugin will have three parameters: `x`, `y`, and `draw`. `x` and `y` are the values of the `mousemove` event and `draw` represents the `inChartArea` parameter, this parameter defines if the event occurred inside of the chart area or not.

Finally, we capture the [`afterDraw`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/api/interfaces/Plugin.html#afterdraw) hook to draw a vertical and horizontal lines based on the `x` and `y` values if the event was triggered inside of the chart area.

ChartJS has [various hooks](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/api/interfaces/Plugin.html) to capture different parts of the chart render cycle.

```js
const plugin = {
    id: 'corsair',
    defaults: {
        width: 1,
        color: '#FF4949',
        dash: [3, 3],
    },
    afterInit: (chart, args, opts) => {
      chart.corsair = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
      }
    },
    afterEvent: (chart, args) => {
      const {inChartArea} = args
      const {type,x,y} = args.event

      chart.corsair = {x, y, draw: inChartArea}
      chart.draw()
    },
    beforeDatasetsDraw: (chart, args, opts) => {
      const {ctx} = chart
      const {top, bottom, left, right} = chart.chartArea
      const {x, y, draw} = chart.corsair
      if (!draw) return

      ctx.save()
      
      ctx.beginPath()
      ctx.lineWidth = opts.width
      ctx.strokeStyle = opts.color
      ctx.setLineDash(opts.dash)
      ctx.moveTo(x, bottom)
      ctx.lineTo(x, top)
      ctx.moveTo(left, y)
      ctx.lineTo(right, y)
      ctx.stroke()
      
      ctx.restore()
    }
  }

const data = {
  labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
  datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      borderWidth: 1
    },
    {
      label: '# of Points',
      data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
      borderWidth: 1
    }
  ]
}
const options = {
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
  hover: {
    mode: 'index',
    intersect: false,
  },
  plugins: {
    corsair: {
      color: 'black',
    }
  }
}
  
const config = {
  type: 'line',
  data,
  options,
  plugins: [plugin],
}

const $chart = document.getElementById('chart')
const chart = new Chart($chart, config)
```

```html
<div class="wrapper" style="width: 98vw; height: 180px">
  <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/chart.js@4.0.1/dist/chart.umd.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is the best answer I've ever seen on SO. Nice one @Teocci

Comment: That is awesome, thank you! Modified it slightly by replacing the 'afterDraw' function with 'beforeDatasetsDraw' as the custom lines were appearing over the tooltips in terms of 'z-index'.

Comment: I updated the code based on your suggestion. Thanks @Andyweb

Answer (score 2):

I have done exactly this (but vertical line only) in a *previous* version of one of my projects. Unfortunately this feature has been removed but the older source code file can still be accessed via my [github](https://github.com/alex-lt-kong/health-manager/blob/53b830e6187f699e2a9c58c51ff9584fda9592fd/templates/chart.html).

The key is this section of the code:

```
Chart.defaults.LineWithLine = Chart.defaults.line;
Chart.controllers.LineWithLine = Chart.controllers.line.extend({
   draw: function(ease) {
      Chart.controllers.line.prototype.draw.call(this, ease);

      if (this.chart.tooltip._active && this.chart.tooltip._active.length) {
         var activePoint = this.chart.tooltip._active[0],
             ctx = this.chart.ctx,
             x = activePoint.tooltipPosition().x,
             topY = this.chart.legend.bottom,
             bottomY = this.chart.chartArea.bottom;

         // draw line
         ctx.save();
         ctx.beginPath();
         ctx.moveTo(x, topY);
         ctx.lineTo(x, bottomY);
         ctx.lineWidth = 0.5;
         ctx.strokeStyle = '#A6A6A6';
         ctx.stroke();
         ctx.restore();
      }
   }
});
```

Another caveat is that the above code works with Chart.js 2.8 and I am aware that the current version of Chart.js is 3.1. I haven't read the official manual on the update but my personal experience is that this update is not 100% backward-compatible--so not sure if it still works if you need Chart.js 3. (But sure you may try 2.8 first and if it works you can then somehow tweak the code to make it work on 3.1)

Comment: Alex thanks, for vertical line has been done for me, but not able to draw horizontally

Comment: emmm...sorry for not reading your question carefully enough...since my code is not online, I cannot try myself...but it seems to me that we can revise these two lines? From `ctx.moveTo(x, topY); ctx.lineTo(x, bottomY);` to `ctx.moveTo(0, y); ctx.lineTo(maxX, y);`?

Comment: but you need to find a way to alculate `maxX`, it is not defined by default, just like `topY` and `bottomY` are defined as aliases of two members of the chartjs object: `topY = this.chart.legend.bottom, bottomY = this.chart.chartArea.bottom;`